# what regular expression would I use to retrieve the digits that follow this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using jQuery to retrieve the class attribute and I need to get the a substring of the digits that follow the substring `"position"`

for example 
`"position7 selected"` I need to retrieve `"7"`

for example 
`"navitem position14 selected"` I need to retrieve `"14"`

I started writing:

```
$(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)$/))
```

But I am getting lost with the regular expression, any help much appreciated.
I actually really really like regular expressions but I'm still learning!

update due to first answer: there might be another group of digits which I need to ignore
For example "navitem2 position14 selected" I need to retrieve "14"

Comment: If you're genuinely interested in learning regular expressions, you should read through [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"navitem position14 selected".match(/position(\d+)/)[1]
```

The call returns `["position14", "14"]`, so the `[1]` element is 14.

You're on the right track with the `(\d+)`, it will match a contiguous group of digits. This just says only match that group when it directly follows the literal string `"position"`.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt has two problems. The first is you anchor it to the end of the string with `$`. So instead of giving you the digits after `position` it will give you digits at the endof the string. At the same time you don't mention `position` at all. What you are looking for is this:

```
var matches = str.match(/position(\d+)/);
```

Now `matches` will be

```
["position14", "14"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace everything that is not a number

```
str.replace(/\D/g,"");
```

If other numbers are present in the string you can still use replace

```
str.replace(/^.*position(\d+).*$/,"$1");
```

However, you may want to go for one of the other regex expressions in the other answers.

Comment: how would that react if there was another group of digits amongst the classes and I'm after the digits that immediately follow "position"?  For example "navitem2 position14 selected" I need to retrieve "14"

Comment: @PrimeLens good point I have provided alternative answer although I couldn't use other answers already given. Don't want to be a copy cat :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  var r = "aaa 1 bb 2 position 113 dd".match(/position\s*(\d+)/)
  if (r instanceof Array )
      return r.pop()
```